# Element after other Element higher on page?

Tags: html, css

I can't get an element to go where I want it to. I am only having this problem because of the way I did my header. I applied `position: absolute`. You can see an example here: http://jacobgasser.com and you can find all the code on there, or you can read down a little farther and I put it there.

I want the text in the top left of the page to be on the white part of the page

Here is the index.html

```
<body onload="loadUp();">
  <div class="menu">
    <a href="https://github.com/jacobgasser" target="_blank"><div 
 class="menuItem">Projects</div></a>
  </div>
  <div class="titleBG">
<h1 class="title" onmouseover="coolThing();"onmouseout="notCoolThing();">Jacob Gasser</h1>
  </div>


<div class="article">
<div class="articleHead">Who am I?</div>

    </div>
<script src="scripts/main.js"></script>
</body>
```

Here is main.css

```
body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.title {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1000%;
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transition: 0.2s;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}
.article {
  font-family: "Arial";
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  margin: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
.articleHead {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  margin: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
}
.menu {
display: block;
color: white;
float: right;
margin-right: 10px;
margin-top: 5px;
opacity: 0;
}
.menuItem {
font-size: 400%;
display: block;
padding-left: 20px;
padding-right: 20px;
-webkit-transition: 0.2s;
border-radius: 5px;
}
.menuItem:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s;
}
.titleBG {
  background-color: #23272A;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
::selection {
  color: #23272A;
  background-color: white;
}

::-moz-selection {
    color: #23272A;
    background-color: white;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: lemon;
  src: url("fonts/LemonMilk.otf");
}
@font-face {
  font-family: cavs;
  src: url("fonts/CaviarDreams.ttf");
}
```

Comment: So where do you want the element (which element?) to go?

Comment: @DavidThomas I'm so sorry, let me update my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution to this issue is to remove the `position: fixed; top: 0;` and adjust the `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` of the page. Just change the CSS for `.titleBG` and `.title` to be the following:

```
.titleBG {
    background-color: #23272A;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
}

.title {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1000%;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: 0.2s;
    margin: 0 /* You can add a margin-left or margin-right if you want, or even margin-bottom, just keep the margin-top at 0*/;
}
```

This will give you the following result:

[image: Click here to view screenshot]